# Get a RouteTemplate by Route Name in MVC Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to generate an object of routes that my JavaScript can reference when making AJAX calls.

I'm using AttributeRouting in MVC 5.2.2.

For example, I have a Controller with attributes as follows:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/my-controller")]
public class MyController : ApiController {
    [Route(Name = "MyController.GetSomeString")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetSomeString()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Then in my Razor view, I have the following:

```
var routes = {
    'MyController.GetSomeString': '@(Url.HttpRouteUrl("MyController.GetSomeString", new {})'
};
```

This produces the following:

```
var routes = {
    'MyController.GetSomeString': '/api/v1/my-controller'
};
```

That's fine, but now I want a route to an action that takes a parameter, but don't have the values for the route data yet. For example, consider the following controller action from the same controller:

```
[Route("{id}/special", Name = "MyController.GetSpecialString")]
[HttpGet]
public string GetSpecialString(string id)
{
    return String.Format("Special string with id {0}.", id);
}
```

I want to produce this string with the tokens in place. I'm calling this the RouteTemplate. I've found no way to retrieve this value:

```
/api/v1/my-controller/{id}/special
```

If I call `HttpRouteUrl` with a empty route values, then I will get an empty string, not the RouteTemplate.

I don't want to provide a value for `{id}`. That's easy. Instead, **I want the `{id}` token in the output string.**

Is this possible? If so, how can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pick this up in your controller via:

```
var url = ((System.Web.Routing.Route)this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Route).Url;
```

Immediate window

> ?url; 
>   "{controller}/{action}/{id}"

Then if you stuff that into the ViewBag or your model etc you can pick it up in your View.

**Edit:**

If you want to access all routes then it would just be:

```
var routeUrls = new List<string>();
foreach (var r in RouteTable.Routes)
{
   routeUrls.Add(((Route)r).Url);
}
```

If you want to filter by the RouteName then you "cant" as per Phil Haacks post about this [Getting the route name for a route](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/11/28/getting-the-route-name-for-a-route.aspx/).

> It's not possible to get the route name of the route because the name
>   is not a property of the Route. When adding a route to a
>   RouteCollection, the name is used as an internal unique index for the
>   route so that lookup for the route is extremely fast. This index is
>   never exposed.

Phil Haack, being Phil Haack, however then goes on to show how this can be done but the caveat being that **this will fail if you add the same routes to multiple collections.**

You create some extension methods to make it easy for you to add the routename to the routes data tokens property:

```
public static Route Map(this RouteCollection routes, string name, 
    string url) {
  return routes.Map(name, url, null, null, null);
}

public static Route Map(this RouteCollection routes, string name, 
    string url, object defaults) {
  return routes.Map(name, url, defaults, null, null);
}

public static Route Map(this RouteCollection routes, string name, 
    string url, object defaults, object constraints) {
  return routes.Map(name, url, defaults, constraints, null);
}

public static Route Map(this RouteCollection routes, string name, 
    string url, object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces) {
  return routes.MapRoute(name, url, defaults, constraints, namespaces)
    .SetRouteName(name);
}

public static string GetRouteName(this Route route) {
    if (route == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return route.DataTokens.GetRouteName();
}

public static string GetRouteName(this RouteData routeData) {
    if (routeData == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return routeData.DataTokens.GetRouteName();
}

public static string GetRouteName(this RouteValueDictionary routeValues) {
    if (routeValues == null) {
        return null;
    }
    object routeName = null;
    routeValues.TryGetValue("__RouteName", out routeName);
    return routeName as string;
}
public static Route SetRouteName(this Route route, string routeName) {
    if (route == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("route");
    }
    if (route.DataTokens == null) {
        route.DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
    }
    route.DataTokens["__RouteName"] = routeName;
    return route;
}
```

And then you simply pull the route name from the Route:

```
var route = routes.Map("rName", "url");
route.GetRouteName();
```

Then you can do something like:

```
Route ajaxRoute = routes.FirstOrDefault(r => ((Route) r).GetRouteName() == "myName"));
```

Comment: I want to get the templates for all routes though, not just the route of the current controller action. I tried looping through `RouteTable.Routes` but they are of internal type `RouteCollectionRoute` and `RouteBase` which don't seem to give access to this type of thing anyways.